# Bounds on $1'A^31$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following question:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix with non-negative entries, and ${\bf 1}$ be the vector of ones. Suppose ${\bf 1}' A {\bf 1}$ is $O(n)$ (big-O of $n$), and $\text{Trace}(A^2)= o(n)$ (small-o of $n$).

Is it true that ${\bf 1}' A^3 {\bf 1}$ is $o(n^2)$ (small-o of $n^2$)?

Comment: The answer is yes; see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial results:**

We define
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{trace}
\|A\|_1 = 1'|A|1 = \sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|\\
\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\tr(A'A)} = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2}
$$
[These are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#.22Entrywise.22_norms) the entrywise $1$-norm and entrywise $2$-norm (AKA Frobenius norm) respectively.  Both are submultiplicative matrix norms.

We note that for any matrix $A$,
$$
\|A\|_2 \leq \|A\|_1 \leq n \|A\|_2
$$
By the information given, we note that
$\|A\|_2^2 = \tr(A'A) = o(n)$.
In particular, this means that $\|A\|_2 = o(\sqrt{n})$.  Now, because the norms are submultiplicative, we also have
$$
\|A^3\|_2 \leq \|A\|_2^3 = o(n^{3/2})
$$
From there, we have
$$
1'A^31 = \|A^3\|_1 \leq n \|A^3\|_2 = o(n^{5/2})=o(n^{2.5})
$$
Which may be the best we can do.

---

The information is $1'A1 = O(n)$ doesn't let us do better directly.  In particular, we have
$$
\|A^3\|_1 \leq \|A\|_1^3 = O(n^3)
$$

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi! You're welcome.  If this answers your question, please "accept" my answer by clicking the $\checkmark$ to the left of my answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I still have one question. How do you show that $||A||_1 \le \sqrt{n} ||A||_2$?. For example, if your $A$ is the matrix of ones.

Comment: One way is using the Cauchy Schwarz inequality.  Note that
$$
|x_1| + \cdots + |x_n|= (|x_1|,\dots,|x_n|) \cdot (1,\dots,1) \leq 
\\
\|(x_1,\dots,x_n)\| \cdot \|(1,\cdots,1)\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2} \cdot \sqrt{n}
$$

Comment: In order to get the matrix inequality, simply treat the matrix as a vector.

Comment: If you view a $n \times n$ matrix as a vector, then you have a vector of $n^2$ entries. Applying C-S ineq. will give you $n$.

Comment: Ah.... you're right.

Comment: $o(n^{2.5}) \implies o(n^2)$?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Could be $\Theta(n^{2.2})$, for example.  I think a counterexample might exist, at least if we only use your second piece of information.